# Applications of the limit $n$th root of $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I have the following question: Given that I've already proven that $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{n}= 1,$$ 
let $a_n = \sqrt[n]{n}$.
I want to prove that $ a_n > a_{n+1}$. My textbook suggests that I should look at the properties of $$ b_n = \left(\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n + 1}}\right)^{n(n+1)} $$ for $ n >2 $.
I felt that this $b_n$ should be an increasing sequence. But I cannot provide a proof (I was thinking of induction, but the book does not cover induction until much later). At this stage it seems I should use
$$ \liminf \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \leq \liminf \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq \limsup \sqrt[n]{a_n} \leq \limsup \dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n},$$
$a_n$ a sequence of positive numbers. This might lead to something, but I am not sure how.

Any point of view would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't get what's $a_n$..

Comment: @Exodd thanks for pointing that out. $a_n = \sqrt[n]{n}$

Answer (score 1):

noting that:
$$
\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \le \frac{n^k}{k!}
$$
we deduce (the final inequality following by termwise comparison)
$$
\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}n^{-k} \lt e
$$
so
$$
\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^{n+1}} \lt \frac{e}{n}
$$
which is less than $1$ if $n \ge 3$

now take the $n(n+1)^{th}$ root of both sides

Comment: Do you happend to know a proof for $ \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \le \frac{n^k}{k!} $ or should be like a very well known inequality?

Comment: cancel the $(n-k)!$ and the numerator becomes $n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$ and this is less than $n^k$ for $k \gt 1$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove that the function $x^{1/x}=\exp(x^{-1}\log x)$ is decreasing. Since $\exp$ is increasing, you need only $\frac{\log x}{x}$ decreasing for $x\geq 3$...

Comment: Well I fell cheat-ish for using functions. Thebook starts with sequences and series.